# create a view from two tables in athena query

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-athena

Basically my use case is that I am creating a view in athena but i want to select the data from two tables depending on the date (snapshot_date) which is given by a column in the tables.  How to do it? I am not finding the syntax for that

```
SELECT
 baseline_year
, marketplace
, locale
, snapshot_time
, ...
FROM
  table1
```

I want to achieve something like if snapshot time is less than 2022-05-01, then use table 2 otherwise use table 1.
Can we any kind of conditioning in FROM? I have explored that we can use CASE_WHEN for performing conditions on columns, but not sure that can be used in FROM?

Comment: Use a join and add the date in your where clause. Otherwise can you provide the structural of your tables?

Comment: 'snapshot time is less than 2022-05-01' - does table 1 contain dates less than 2022-05-01? if not UNION another query to table 2

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi    yeah sure. SO i have built athena table over csv file which contains columns like marketplace, ..., snapshot time etc. Both the tables contains the same set of columns just that one table contains only the data where snapshot date is from 2022-04-01 to 2022-04-30 (YYYY-MM-DD). another table contain some dates of april also but For april i want to use table 1 and after that i want to use table 2.

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah one table contains dates less than 2022-05-01 but another tables neccessarily does not contain dates after 2022-05-01. it has dates from around 2022-04-26.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you meant to use table2 if the snapshot_time is earlier than 2022-05-01 and use table1 if the snapshot_time is greater than or equal to 2022-05-01 **REGARDLESS** of what shapshot_time those two tables have.

```
SELECT ... FROM table1 where date(snapshot_time)>= '2022-05-01'
union
SELECT ... FROM table2 where date(snapshot_time) < '2022-05-01' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with a parametrized view, try to create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func() RETURNS DATE
  RETURN @var;
```

Then create the view :

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS
SELECT
 T1.baseline_year
, T1.marketplace
, T1.locale
, T1.snapshot_time
, ...
FROM  table1 AS T1
WHERE DATE(T1.snapshot_time) >= func()
UNION
SELECT
 T2...,
 ..
FROM
  table1 AS T2
WHERE DATE(T2.snapshot_time) <= func()
```